# Two options for Windows 10 in the GRUB menu in dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors

I have two options for Windows 10 in the GRUB menu, one labelled `/dev/sda1` and one`/dev/sda3`

[image: GRUB menu]

Can I remove one of them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Probably one is the Windows recovery boot.

Comment: Both options were booting windows but sda 1 was not able to shutdown windows. sda3 was OK. I deleted sda1 through disk management which was of 500 MB and system reserved now windows is working fine through sda 3 but still sda1 option is there on grub menu  and I cannot boot through sda 1 now, in sda 1 it is showing no boot files found but sda 3 is working fine

Answer (score 0):

They might be a recovery Partition on sda1 or sda3. I sugesst you to try to boot each one of them to see what happens.

With [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) you can edit the eintries with a GUI.

Comment: Both options were booting windows but sda 1 was not able to shutdown windows. sda3 was OK. I deleted sda1 through disk management which was of 500 MB and system reserved now windows is working fine through sda 3 but still sda1 option is there on grub menu and I cannot boot through sda 1 now, in sda 1 it is showing no boot files found but sda 3 is working fine

Comment: @AtherHussain from Ubuntu, execute `sudo update-grub` - this regenerates the menu entries. If that doesn't help you should edit your question with further details of what you've tried :)